# How to design a zero-phase bandpass filter for 1 to 20 Hz in matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter

I am using Matlab to filter ECG data. There is noise in the data and I have tried using a Butterfilter. The problem is that there a higher power butter filter, anything above 3 makes the data disappear.

I have looked through Matlab's Help guide on filter design but I am unclear and still confused on how to actually use it and implement it.

Goal: Filter ECG data with zero phase distortion, filter all outside 1 to 20 Hz

My code right now:

```
%takes in one channel of data from the dataMatrix, plots it, filters, and plots again in a new figure

channel = 150;
x = dataMatrix(:,channel);

plot(x)
rawTitle = sprintf('Raw Channel %d ', channel);
title(rawTitle)

figure
[b_pass a_pass] = butter(3, [1/1000 20/1000], 'bandpass');
plot(filtfilt(b_pass, a_pass, x))
channelTitle=sprintf('Filtered Channel %d ', channel);
title(channelTitle)
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: lol thanks for the feedback, really helps me move forward.

Comment: I am not qualified in matlab to help. But it is a good habit to have a clean looking question to improve the chance of getting answered :). Sorry if it felt a bit harsh ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Designing the filter

Let's start with the basics of designing the Butterworth-filter in Matlab. Here, we can only define a filter using normalized frequencies. Therefore we need to know the sampling frequency `fs` to determine the normalized frequency `fn` like this: `fn = f/fs`. Then we need the order `order` and the two cutoff-frequencies `fc1` and `fc2`. The second argument of `butter` takes 'frequencies' from 0 to 1 where 1 corresponds to the Nyquist-rate which is the half of the sampling frequency `fs`. Therefore we have to divide `fs` by 2 in the second argument.

```
[b,a] = butter(order, [fc1,fc2]/(fs/2), 'bandpass');
```

### Application

Now we can go into your code and apply the filter. Note that `filtfilt` is zero-phase and doubles the order of the original filter. We can take some sample data from [here](http://www.clear.rice.edu/elec301/Projects02/empiricalMode/code/ecg.mat) (`fs` assumed to be 500Hz) and see if it works as expected.

```
% load sample data and assign it to x
load('ecg.mat');
fs = 500;
x = ecg;

% define to use OP's code
channel = 150;

% plot the raw data
figure
plot(x)
rawTitle = sprintf('Raw Channel %d ', channel);
title(rawTitle)

% design filter
[b_pass,a_pass] = butter(3,[1,20]/(fs/2), 'bandpass');

% filter data and plot it
figure
plot(filtfilt(b_pass, a_pass, x))
channelTitle=sprintf('Filtered Channel %d ', channel);
title(channelTitle)
```

*This is the result:*

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you Matt, I was just informed that I am close but my grad student wants to see a FIR filter and butter makes an IIR filter, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Since no more specifications are given you could do something along the lines of `b_pass = fir1(400,[1,20]/(fs/2)); a_pass = 1;`. The result may not be satisfying for the lower frequencies. To design a better FIR-filter, have a look at the documentation [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/fir-filter-design.html) or/and use `fdatool`. The designed filter can be exported to Matlab-code, so you'll get exactly what you want.